# Does Not Recognize Textfield as Empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I can't get the code to recognize when the HourGoal and MinuteGoal textfields are empty. They never come up as having a nil value or being empty, causing the program to crash when I try to unwrap the values.

```
import UIKit

class ReadingGoal: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var HourGoal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MinuteGoal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var NextButton: UIButton!
    var mingoal = Int()
    var hrgoal = Int()
    var secondstoread:Int = 0
    var initialtime:Int = Int()

    @IBAction func HourEditingDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
        NextButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func MinuteEditingDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
        NextButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    func disable() {
        NextButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func NextButtonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("GERALDINE IS AWESOME!!!!!")

        // ERROR
        if HourGoal.text?.isEmpty == false || MinuteGoal.text?.isEmpty == false {
            if HourGoal.text != nil && HourGoal.text?.isEmpty == false{
             //   self.hrgoal = Int(HourGoal.text!)!
                print("hr Value exists")
                print("\(HourGoal.text!)")
            }
            else {
                NextButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            if MinuteGoal.text != nil && MinuteGoal.text?.isEmpty == false{
              // self.mingoal = Int(MinuteGoal.text!)!
                print("min value exists")
                print("\(MinuteGoal.text!)")
            }
            else {
                NextButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            print("in ")
            // secondstoread = ((mingoal + (hrgoal*60))*60)
            secondstoread = 10

            if secondstoread > 0 {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Mr.Friar-DavisIsAGiantBallOfFloof", sender: self)
            }
            else {
                NextButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            //function saves text field info to core data
        }
    }

    //for the specific segue 'toBookInfo', certain information is passed through the segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //making sure we are using correct segue
        if segue.identifier == "Mr.Friar-DavisIsAGiantBallOfFloof" {

                //selecting the destination controller
                let detailVC: TimerController = segue.destination as! TimerController

                //sending properties to destination view controller
                detailVC.seconds = secondstoread
            }
    else {
            // Error sender is not a cell or cell is not in collectionView.
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initialtime = secondstoread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't be teaching you terminology here, but all variables should begin with **lowerCase** like this, even the IBOutlets...

...Okay I studied your code for a while:

**AVOID USING EXLAMATION MARK AT ANY COST!!!** 
   -> The reason it crashes a lot because you use ! everywhere, that force unwraps the optionals and totally ruins the beauty of swift.

How is that this line works with compiler having no problem with optionals?

```
if HourGoal.text?.isEmpty == false || MinuteGoal.text?.isEmpty == false
```

you are somehow checking optional value and the value is definitely nil, so before the line of code provide:

```
guard let hourGoalText = HourGoal.text, let minuteGoal = minuteGoal.text else { //handle code for empty textField
return }
```

This is first step for checking optionals... now the code won't crash... But honestly without debug

if you use the guard let or if let statements, you won't have trouble with crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can check `textfield` emptiness in different ways. Some of them are:

```
if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true{
    print("textField is empty")
} 
else{
      print("textField has some text")
}
```

or

```
if textfield.text?.characters.count==0 {
  print("textField is empty")
}
else{
     print("textField has some text")
}
```

or

```
if textfield.text == "" {
     print("textField is empty")
}
else{
     print("textField has some text")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if let` or `guard` for unwrapping in a safe way.
Something like this

```
if let texthour = HourGoal.text{
       // has text and can be "", next check for blank string
       if texthour == ""{

     }
}
```

OR use `guard` as Dominik shows